# IE11 displays the same page differently regular page vs VS debugging

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to fix the issue of a page that doesn't displayed properly in my IE11 when I go to my website.
If I debug this page locally from the VS2012 to fix this issue, it is displayed properly. Why is that happening? Why it is different? What am I missing?

The browser that opens the page from the VS2012 is the same browser IE11.

Can it happen with the same source code? Does the VS2012 applies some settings to the IE11 (compatibility mode settings etc) that are different for the debug mode? Seems like everything's the same.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you debugging? Local IIS or VS Dev Server? Definitely need more info - what kind of site, what looks different, etc.

Comment: Does IE11 still have that silly tendency to display locally hosted pages in compatibility mode?